# Pygame Image Movement Anomaly

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using Pygame to develop a simple hobby project. I have an image that I want to "slide out" onto the screen. It doesn't "slide out" at a reliable speed.

The image and window are 1024x768. I slide it out horizontally from right to left. Using the pygame API, I have the render speed set to 40 FPS. I want to control the speed at which it slides onto the screen (1 sec, 2 secs, etc.), so I came up with this little formula that controls how fast the image slides each frame:

```
slide_pixels = image_width / (frames_per_sec * slide_time_in_secs)
```

So, for a 1024 wide image sliding out in one second, the image should slide out at about 25 pixels per frame (1024 / (40 x 1)). That's 25.6 pixels to be exact, but this isn't required to be that precise. The problem is that the image is sliding out much faster than it should be. For the simplest case, one second, it seems about right. But for two, five, ten, etc., it slides out much faster. I've print out the deltas (slide_pixels), and each time they seem correct, so it should be sliding at the correct speed, and the screen seems to be refreshing at the correct rate (40 frames per second).

Here is the pertinent code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import pygame
import sys


class MyMain:

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption("My Project")

        # set FPS
        self.__clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.__clock.tick(40)

        self.__screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1024, 768], pygame.DOUBLEBUF, 32)
        self.__mousePosition = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # Load resources
        title_path = os.path.join("..", "Assets", "Images", "TitleScreen.png")
        self.__titleImage = pygame.image.load(title_path)

        pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

    def start(self):
        self.event_handler()

    def event_handler(self):

        # setup for loop
        title_x, title_y = 1024, 0
        self.__screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        #
        # This is where the problem is?
        #
        slide_in_time = 10 # in seconds
        slide_pixels = title_x / (40 * slide_in_time)

        # Render loop
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            # animate and draw image
            if title_x >= 0:
                title_x -= slide_pixels
                if title_x < 0:
                    title_x = 0
            self.__screen.blit(self.__titleImage, (title_x, title_y))

            pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyMain().start()
```

I am new to Python and Pygame. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `self.__clock.tick(40)` every frame, otherwise the game will run with the maximum frame rate that your CPU can achieve.